# Dados da SessionStorage so carrega apos refresh da pagina

Tags: vue.js, session

Estou usando os dados do SessionStorage para exibir o nome de usuário na tela. O nome deve carregar após o login, mas a informação só é carregada quando eu atualizo a página (clicando em recarregar). Alguem sabe por quê?

```
    HTML
<cv-header-name to="/"> Welcome {{ userName }}</cv-header-name>


VUE
  data: function () {
   return {
   userName: [],
   };
  },
  mounted() {
    if(sessionStorage.getItem('name')) {
  try {
    this.userName = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('name'))
  }catch (error) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('name')
  }
}
```

Antes do refresh da pagina
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois do refresh
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem que ver o código que faz o `sessionStorage.setItem('name',....)` e analisar, junto do código da pergunta, a sequencia de eventos do login para conhecer a dinâmica do código com os dados no sessionStorage.

Answer (score -2):

Se você está querendo acessar o sessionStorage do browser, acredito que você precise acessar usando "window".

```
window.sessionStorage.getItem('name')
```